# Example of Spring Boot + Vaadin 14 + bootJar + Gradle

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, vaadin, executable-jar

I have a working application running in STS IDE... I thought that it would be simple to build a runnable jar since it is a spring boot application but now I am no longer sure. There seems to be no clear guide anywhere on how to build the frontend bundle and allow it to be packaged in the runnable jar. I tried the Vaadin plugin for Gradle but I couldn't get it to work...
Is there a working example somewhere?

Thanks.

Here is the gist of  build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'com.vaadin' version '0.14.3.7'
}

group = 'dsto.eosil.cc'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons'
    }
}

ext {
    set('vaadinVersion', "14.4.4")
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'com.vaadin:vaadin-spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core'
    
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-mockmvc'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit-test'
    testImplementation 'com.h2database:h2'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "com.vaadin:vaadin-bom:${vaadinVersion}"
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

vaadin {
    productionMode=true
    pnpmEnable=true
}

defaultTasks("clean", "vaadinBuildFrontend", "bootJar")
```

When I did finally built the frontend and packaged it in the jar file, I run it and found the frontend is broken.  The browser gives me this error...

[image: vaadin bundle error in browser]

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: I built runnable jars (Spring Boot, Vaadin 14) with Maven. There are some options that make things a bit confusing. Options like vaadin.productionMode, vaadin.compatibilityMode, and original.frontend.resources in the application.properties.

Comment: Please be explicit how you "build and package the frontend". `gradle -DproductionMode=true vaadinBuildFrontend jar` ?

Comment: Since I only use Java, I didn't need Maven goal vaadin:build-frontend. https://vaadin.com/docs/flow/production/tutorial-production-mode-basic.html

Answer (score 0):

Eventually found out that this is due to deprecated components (Something I am not happy with Vaadin dependencies).  Something somewhere breaks but the error shows up in something seemingly totally unrelated.  In this case, it is the apexcharts that I need to upgrade.